# robust and clustered standard error in R for probit and logit regression

Tags: r

Originally, I mainly want to run a probit/logit model with clustered standard error in R which is quite intuitive in Stata. I came across with the answer here [Logistic regression with robust clustered standard errors in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16498849/logistic-regression-with-robust-clustered-standard-errors-in-r). 
    Therefore, I tried to compare the result from Stata and from R both with the robust standard error and clustered standard error. But I noticed that the outputs for both standard errors across software are not exactly the same. However, if I use the method suggested here https://diffuseprior.wordpress.com/2012/06/15/standard-robust-and-clustered-standard-errors-computed-in-r/. I can get the exact output both from R and Stata for linear regression. Therefore,I am afraid wether the code I wrote in R is not correct and what command to use if I want to run a probit model instead of a logit model.Or if there is any elegant alternatives to solve this? Thanks.

R code

```
## 1. linear regression
library(rms) 
# model<-lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width,iris)
summary(model)
fit=ols(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, x=T, y=T, data=iris)
fit
robcov(fit) #robust standard error
robcov(fit, cluster=iris$Species) #clustered standard error


## 2. logistic regression
##demo data generation   
set.seed(1234)
subj<-rep(1:20,each=4)
con1<-rep(c(1,0),40)
con2<-rep(c(1,1,0,0),20) 
effect<-rbinom(80,1,0.34)
data<-data.frame(subj,con1,con2,effect)
library(foreign);write.dta(data,'demo_data.dta')

library(rms)
fit=lrm(effect ~ con1 + con2, x=T, y=T, data=data)
fit
robcov(fit)  ##robust standard error
robcov(fit, cluster=data$subj) ## clustered standard error
```

Stata code

```
## 1. linear regression
webuse iris
reg seplen sepwid petlen petwid
reg seplen sepwid petlen petwid,r
reg seplen sepwid petlen petwid,cluster(iris)


## 2. logistic regression

use demo_data,clear
logit effect con1 con2
logit effect con1 con2,r
logit effect con1 con2,cluster(subj)
```

Comment: Could you specify what `not exactly the same` means? There are a lot of defaults involved that are probably different. It is a priori unclear which defaults are better. But if you want to get exactly the same values, you need to figure out which defaults `Stata` and `robcov` use, and adjust them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have edited my question to give additional information

Comment: Is it possible that you are using logit without first running logistic? "`logistic` displays estimates as odds ratios; to view coefficients, type logit after running logistic"  ([source](http://www.stata.com/manuals13/rlogistic.pdf#rlogistic))

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it should not affect the P values which are not consistent across the two softwares.

Comment: The stata output is the same as the one achieved through vcovHC. Actually I just checked the method proposed here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927766/logit-binomial-regression-with-clustered-standard-errors), I can get the same output as the one I get from stata, so still be curious how I can achieve this using **rms** package.

Comment: Nothing special, I just want to run the logit/probit regression with clustered standard error and saw that package **rms** are designed to do this. Can you further edit your answer a bit to make it output the result including the P values automatically with the Sandwich package? Thanks.

Comment: Seen that, thanks, I will go through this carefully and will give you feedback later.

Comment: New package that might be of interest to you: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multiwayvcov/multiwayvcov.pdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I prefer the `sandwich` package to compute robust standard errors. One reason is its excellent documentation. See `vignette("sandwich")` which clearly shows all available defaults and options, and the [corresponding article](https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v016i09/v16i09.pdf) which explains how you can use `?sandwich` with custom `bread` and `meat` for special cases.

We can use `sandwich` to figure out the difference between the options you posted. The difference will most likely be the degree of freedom correction. Here a comparison for the simple linear regression:

```
library(rms)
library(sandwich)

fitlm <-lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width,iris)

#Your Blog Post:
X <- model.matrix(fitlm)
n <- dim(X)[1]; k <- dim(X)[2]; dfc <- n/(n-k)    
u <- matrix(resid(fitlm))
meat1 <- t(X) %*% diag(diag(crossprod(t(u)))) %*% X
Blog <- sqrt(dfc*diag(solve(crossprod(X)) %*% meat1 %*% solve(crossprod(X))))

# rms fits:
fitols <- ols(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, x=T, y=T, data=iris)
Harrell <- sqrt(diag(robcov(fitols, method="huber")$var))
Harrell_2 <- sqrt(diag(robcov(fitols, method="efron")$var))

# Variations available in sandwich:    
variations <- c("const", "HC0", "HC1", "HC2","HC3", "HC4", "HC4m", "HC5")
Zeileis <- t(sapply(variations, function(x) sqrt(diag(vcovHC(fitlm, type = x)))))
rbind(Zeileis, Harrell, Harrell_2, Blog)

          (Intercept) Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
const       0.2507771  0.06664739   0.05671929   0.1275479
HC0         0.2228915  0.05965267   0.06134461   0.1421440
HC1         0.2259241  0.06046431   0.06217926   0.1440781
HC2         0.2275785  0.06087143   0.06277905   0.1454783
HC3         0.2324199  0.06212735   0.06426019   0.1489170
HC4         0.2323253  0.06196108   0.06430852   0.1488708
HC4m        0.2339698  0.06253635   0.06482791   0.1502751
HC5         0.2274557  0.06077326   0.06279005   0.1454329
Harrell     0.2228915  0.05965267   0.06134461   0.1421440
Harrell_2   0.2324199  0.06212735   0.06426019   0.1489170
Blog        0.2259241  0.06046431   0.06217926   0.1440781
```

1. The result from the blog entry is equivalent to `HC1`. If the blog entry is similar to your `Stata` output, `Stata` uses `HC1`.
2. Frank Harrel's function yields results similar to `HC0`. As far as I understand, this was the first proposed solution and when you look through `vignette(sandwich)` or the articles mentioned in `?sandwich::vcovHC`, other methods have slightly better properties. They differ in their degree of freedom adjustments. Also note that the call to `robcov(., method = "efron")` is similar to `HC3`.

In any case, if you want identical output, use `HC1` or just adjust the variance-covariance matrix approriately. After all, after looking at `vignette(sandwich)` for the differences between different versions, you see that you just need to rescale with a constant to get from `HC1` to `HC0`, which should not be too difficult. By the way, note that `HC3` or `HC4` are typically preferred due to better small sample properties, and their behavior in the presence of influential observations. So, you probably want to change the defaults in `Stata`.

You can use these variance-covariance matrices by supplying it to appropriate functions, such as `lmtest::coeftest` or `car::linearHypothesis`. For instance:

```
library(lmtest)
coeftest(fitlm, vcov=vcovHC(fitlm, "HC1"))

t test of coefficients:

              Estimate Std. Error t value  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.855997   0.225924  8.2151 1.038e-13 ***
Sepal.Width   0.650837   0.060464 10.7640 < 2.2e-16 ***
Petal.Length  0.709132   0.062179 11.4046 < 2.2e-16 ***
Petal.Width  -0.556483   0.144078 -3.8624 0.0001683 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

For cluster-robust standard errors, you'll have to adjust the meat of the sandwich (see `?sandwich`) or look for a [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33927766/logit-binomial-regression-with-clustered-standard-errors) doing that. There are already [several](https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v016i09/v16i09.pdf) [sources](http://drewdimmery.com/robust-ses-in-r/) [explaining](http://www.ne.su.se/polopoly_fs/1.216115.1426234213!/menu/standard/file/clustering1.pdf) in [excruciating](http://www.r-bloggers.com/easy-clustered-standard-errors-in-r/) [detail](https://thetarzan.wordpress.com/2011/06/11/clustered-standard-errors-in-r/) [how](http://rforpublichealth.blogspot.se/2014/10/easy-clustered-standard-errors-in-r.html) [to](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10017/standard-error-clustering-in-r-either-manually-or-in-plm) [do](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plm/docs/vcovhc) [it](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/miceadds/html/lm.cluster.html) [with](http://dynaman.net/) [appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155638/clustered-standard-errors-in-r-using-plm-with-fixed-effects) [codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389843/double-clustered-standard-errors-for-panel-data) [or](http://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/gov2001/files/sesection_5.pdf) [functions](http://www.existencia.org/pro/?p=134). There is no reason for me to reinvent the wheel here, so I skip this.

There is also a relatively new and convenient package computing cluster-robust standard errors for linear models and generalized linear models. See [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multiwayvcov/multiwayvcov.pdf).

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, but does it address the question? It looks like OP seeks to estimate a probit model in R.

Comment: The procedure would be pretty much the same in how to adjust the standard errors.