# R : Clustered standard errors in fractional probit model

Tags: r

I need to estimate a fractional (response taking values between 0 and 1) model with R. I also want to cluster the standard errors. I have found several examples in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37528990/robust-and-clustered-standard-error-in-r-for-probit-and-logit-regression?noredirect=1&lq=1) and elsewhere and I built this function based on my findings:

```
require(sandwich)
require(lmtest)
clrobustse <- function(fit, cl){
    M <- length(unique(cl))
    N <- length(cl)
    K <- fit$rank
    dfc <- (M/(M - 1))*((N - 1)/(N - K))
    uj <- apply(estfun(fit), 2, function(x) tapply(x, cl, sum))
    vcovCL <- dfc*sandwich(fit, meat = crossprod(uj)/N)
    coeftest(fit, vcovCL)
}
```

I estimate my model like this:

```
fit <- glm(dep ~ exp1 + exp2 + exp3, data = df, fam = quasibinomial("probit"))
clrobustse(fit, df$cluster)
```

Everything works fine and I get the results. However, I suspect that something is not right as the non-clustered version:

```
coeftest(fit)
```

gives the exact same standard errors. I checked that Stata reports and that displays different clustered errors. I suspect that I have misspecified the function `clrobustse` but I just don't know how. Any ideas about what could be going wrong here?

Comment: You probably don't need to write your own function. Try the `multiwayvcov` package, or `plm::vcovHC`. This question on [stats.se] may help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10017/standard-error-clustering-in-r-either-manually-or-in-plm

Comment: Thank you! `multiwayvcov` was a good find. There's some difference to Stata std. errors but only around fourth or fifth digit. Somehow `vcovHC` did not replicate Stata results very closely at all.