# How to run fixed-effects logit model with clustered standard errors and survey weights in R?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, weighted

I am using Afrobarometer survey data using 2 rounds of data for 10 countries. My DV is a binary 0-1 variable. I need to use logistic regression, fixed-effects, clustered standard errors (at country), and weighted survey data.  A variable for the weights already exists in the dataframe.

I've been looking at help files for the following packages: clogit, glm, pglm, glm2, zelig, bife , etc. Typical errors include: can't add weights, can't do fixed effects, cant do either or etc.

```
#Glm 

t3c1.fixed <- glm(formula = ethnic ~ elec_prox + 
elec_comp + round + country, data=afb, 
weights = afb$survey_weight, 
index c("country", "round"), 
family=binomial(link='logit'))

#clogit 

t3c1.fixed2 <- clogit(formula = ethnic ~ elec_prox + 
elec_comp + round + country, data=afb, 
weights = afb$survey_weight, 
method=c("within"))


#bife attempt 

library(bife)
t3c1.fixed3 <- bife(ethnic ~ elec_prox + elec_comp + round + 
country, model = logit,data=afb, 
weights = afb$survey_weight, 
bias_corr = "ana")
```

I either get error messages or the code doesn't include one of the conditions I need to include, so I can't use them. In Stata it appears this process is very simple, but in R it seems rather tedious. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could calculate FE logit with a package that accepts weights, e.g. `clogit` and calculate cluster SEs manually after by adjusting the vcov-matrix, e.g. with the `sandwich` package. You may want to look into this helpful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37529874/6574038 Maybe you also could consider fixed effects dummies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would check out the `survey` package which provides everything for which you are asking. The first step is to create the survey object, specify the survey weights and then you are off to the races.

```
library(survey)
my_survey <- svydesign(ids= ~1, strata = ~country, wts = ~wts, data = your_data)

# Then you can use the survey glm to do what you want via

svy_fit <- svy_glm(ethnic ~ elec_prox + 
elec_comp + round + country, data = my_survey, family = binomial())
```

Or at least I would go down this path given you are using survey data.